# graphing equations of $y$ instead of $x$

Tags: calculus, integration, graphing-functions

The problem I'm attempting is: Sketch the curves $\ x = y^2 − 4y$ and $\ x = 2y − y^2$, find their points of intersection, and find the area enclosed by the curves.

I'm confused as to how to graph the curves because they're given as x=... I tried to solve for y to get the function in terms of x but I couldn't isolate y on it's own.

I can see by using a graphing calculator that the curves are sideways parabolas (hyperbolas?) and I can set the equations equal to each other to find the intersection points $(-3,3)$, $(0,0)$

I would then find the area by integrating $\ \int_{0}^{3} {[(2y-y^2) - (y^2-4y)]} dy$ which I calculated to be 9.

Can someone please explain how I go about graphing a function that is given in terms of $y$ instead of $x$. I tried to look it up but I couldn't find anything.

Thanks

Comment: Turn the paper sideways and graph like normal. Then turn to the normal orientation of the paper.

Comment: Draw your coordinate axes with $y$ horizontal and $x$ vertical and then graph it like normal (except for the new positions of $x$ and $y$).  Then to get back to the regular axes you'll need to flip the graph over the $x$ axis AND then the $y$ axis.

Comment: Or see [here](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/Alg/InverseFunctions.aspx) or [here](http://www.kkuniyuk.com/PrecalcBook/Precalc0108to0109.pdf) or [here](http://dl.uncw.edu/digilib/mathematics/algebra/mat111hb/functions/inverse/inverse.html) or [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function).

Comment: remember in your integral $\int_0^3[(2y-y^2) -(y^2-4y)]dy, y$ is a dummy variable, so you can change all the $y$ to $x$ including $dy$ to $dx.$ now, you can draw $y = 2x - x^2$ and $y = x^2 - 4x$ to your hearts content.